# No hdmi signal - Dell precision 7740

Tags: drivers, kernel, graphics, hdmi, intel

Ubuntu 20.04.3, kernel 5.11.0-37-generic, Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 630 4.6 - 21.2.2

I'm not getting any signal output to hdmi.  I went through and upgraded the drivers to the latest stable, but this is also a fresh install of Ubuntu.
I had this problem before the fresh install, but was able to fix it when I upgraded the kernel to 5.8 and updated my graphics drivers, shortly after that my system board died completely.  I got Dell to replace it, but then my OS wouldn't boot, so after some effort to make sure I had everything backed up and after trying the repair and OS re-install on the system I had to create a live usb install and re-install from scratch using that.
Now I have a more updated version of the OS than I had before and I think this is a different graphics card than was on the other system board.  Either way I upgraded the graphics drivers and the 5.11 appears to be the latest stable kernel.  So now what????

Comment: Already said, I had to reload the OS because it wouldn't boot after the system board was replaced and the repair features didn't work.  Kept giving me a kernel error message and would only boot with partial functionality into an older kernel.  It has a fresh install..

Comment: Did not see the re install in tat continuous run on sentence. Any way people are using up to the 5.14 kernel to get past hardware problems.